# TCP message corruption

Tags: tcp

This is a very general/conceptual question but I want to expose something that I have been facing recently:

I am using a TCP connection between two processes in the same machine.

How on earth is it possible that the sender process sends something like:

**"hello world"**

And the receiver process receives something like:

**"hello 5world"**

Of course the character "5" can be any other character, it is just an example, but the point here is that somehow the message is corrupted (by the way, this error occurr very rarely).

Is it possible that this error comes from TCP itself? (Which of course would be extremely rare since tcp reliability is practically 100% (99.9999999999%)).

Has some ever experienced something similar?

Having an extra character at the end would be a more expectable bug (due by some programmer mistake), but again, that's not the case.

Comment: $5 says it's a careless bug in the code that's consuming the socket API - it _won't_ be corruption on-the-wire (or in-the-buffer, in `localhost` loopback connections). One possibility is one-side is using a buffer that isn't zeroed-out before use and they aren't checking the return-value from `read()` or they have an off-by-1 error when figuring out where to write into the buffer, etc. **Show us your code** otherwise we're just speculating (and wasting time).

Comment: Well you don't need to zero any buffers before use: this is cargo-cult programming [@Dai]; but you certainly do need to make proper use of the result returned by `read()`, and clearly you aren't. Perhaps you are using string functions on the received buffer? Don't,

Comment: @user207421 "clearly you aren't"... eh? No-one has posted any code so you can't come to that that conclusion yet.

Comment: @Dai I will see your $5 and raise you $10 on that.

Comment: "_you don't need to zero any buffers before use: this is cargo-cult programming; you don't need to zero any buffers before use: this is cargo-cult programming_" - you're not wrong, but zereoing out buffers in debug builds does help with troublehooting (e.g. if we see non-zero bytes in the wrong place) - so it isn't cargo-cult in all cases (and many APIs _do_ require buffers to be zeroed-out, such as Win32)

Comment: @Dai You don't need to do it; *ergo* it is cargo-cult programming, and incidentally it will hide other bugs. You just have to use the `read()` result properly. I haven't zeroed a buffer in three decades.